# How to use Tiled for 2d based maps?

Tags: android, graphics, maps, tiles, andengine

I am using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) to try and create a map for a example project for a 2d game. I have no idea on how to use tiled. And i dont see any good tutorials of how to Create the tiles around google..

How do you create the tiles such as grass, or a tree to go the the Tiled map?

Any tutorials or answers are welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Tileset by going to Map > Create Tileset. Then you need to provide an image and you can start creating your level! But the TMX tile map's in AndEngine are really slow, so I would suggest that using your own XML format would be better. But then you might have to write your own level editor.